# Resource attributes and 'require'

Tags: puppet

From documentation, it looks like the attribute 'require' does not exist for resource types such as 'exec', 'package', 'file', etc.

I've seen several posts on stackoverflow where folks have been showing examples of using 'require' as an attribute to perform some kind of resource ordering and dependencies. Require appears to be a class function only.

Has there been changes to this? Or is the community misled about the usage of 'require' as a resource attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Has there been changes to this?

No.

> Or is the community misled about the usage of 'require' as a resource attribute?

No.

`require` is one of Puppet's [*metaparameters*](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.4/reference/metaparameter.html).  These can be used with every resource type, including custom types and defined types.  This has been the case since before the earliest Puppet I have experience with, v0.24.8.  Since they apply to every single resource type, and have exactly the same meaning for each, they are documented in their own section (linked above).  The language reference [also discusses them and their universal nature](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.4/reference/lang_resources.html#metaparameters).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I realized that Puppets documentation on resource types does have the attribute list, but I missed that last line in that block which sorta cut off the meta parameter information, which led me down a path of my own hosed up logic.